# How to avoid global variable declaration when using Perl's dynamic scoping?

Tags: perl, scope, global-variables, dynamic-scope

I am trying to write a perl script that calls a function written somewhere else (by someone else) which manipulates some of the variables in my script's scope. Let's say the script is `main.pl` and the function is there in `funcs.pm`. My `main.pl` looks like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package plshelp;
use funcs;

my $var = 3;
print "$var\n";   # <--- prints 3

{                 # New scope somehow prevents visibility of $pointer outside
    local our $pointer = \$var;
    change();
}

print "$var\n";   # <--- Ideally should print whatever funcs.pm wanted
```

For some reason, using `local our $pointer;` prevents visibility of `$pointer` outside the scope. But if I just use `our $pointer;`, the variable can be seen outside the scope in `main.pl` using `$plshelp::pointer` (but not in `funcs.pm`, so it would be useless anyway). As a side-note, could someone please explain this?

`funcs.pm` looks something like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package plshelp;

sub change
{
    ${$pointer} = 4;
}
```

I expected this to change the value of `$var` and print `4` when the main script was run. But I get a compile error saying `$pointer` wasn't declared. This error can be removed by adding `our $pointer;` at the top of `change` in `funcs.pm`, but that would create an unnecessary global variable that is visible everywhere. We can also remove this error by removing the `use strict;`, but that seems like a bad idea. We can also get it to work by using `$plshelp::pointer` in `funcs.pm`, but the person writing `funcs.pm` doesn't want to do that.

Is there a good way to achieve this functionality of letting `funcs.pm` manipulate variables in my scope without declaring global variables? If we were going for global variables anyway, I guess I don't need to use dynamic scoping at all.

Let's just say it's not possible to pass arguments to the function for some reason.

**Update**

It seems that `local our` isn't doing any "special" as far as preventing visibility is concerned. From [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html):

> This means that when `use strict 'vars'` is in effect, `our` lets you use a package variable without qualifying it with the package name, but only within the lexical scope of the our declaration. This applies immediately--even within the same statement.

and

> This works even if the package variable has not been used before, as package variables spring into existence when first used.

So this means that `$pointer` "exists" even after we leave the curly braces. Just that we have to refer to it using `$plshelp::pointer` instead of just `$pointer`. But since we used `local` before initializing `$pointer`, it is still undefined outside the scope (although it is still "declared", whatever that means). A clearer way to write this would be `(local (our $pointer)) = \$var;`. Here, `our $pointer` "declares" `$pointer` and returns `$pointer` as well. We now apply `local` on this returned value, and this operation returns `$pointer` again which we are assigning to `\$var`.

But this still leaves the main question of whether there is a good way of achieving the required functionality unanswered.

Comment: This is a good explanation of something overly complicated. Why do you want to do this? In most cases this is not a good idea.

Comment: As to the purpose of  `change`, the idea is to expose a "handle" for someone else to influence the script without having to actually modify the script. So some functions like `change` would be in a file (like `funcs.pm`) and this person will just have to change that file to influence some stuff happening in the main script. The way this was set up was to have a pre-agreed upon set of variable names that would be messed around with in `funcs.pm` (passing arguments is probably a much better idea).

Comment: A couple of notes. The [package](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html) "_declares the BLOCK or **the rest of the compilation unit**_" (my emphasis) as being in that namespace; so the posted sample program doesn't even have `main::`  (2) As shown `change` is in `plshelp` package, not `funcs` as implied in a comment. So it'd be `plshelp::change()`, but if you export the symbol `change` from `plshelp` package and import it in the caller then you can just say `change()`. Nothing from the `use`d package `funcs` is seen in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's be clear about how global variables with `our` work and why they have to be declared: There's a difference between the storage of a global variable, and visibility of its unqualified name. Under `use strict`, undefined variable names will not implicitly refer to a global variable.

- We can always access the global variable with its fully qualified name, e.g. `$Foo::bar`.
- If a global variable in the current package already exists at compile time and is marked as an imported variable, we can access it with an unqualified name, e.g. `$bar`. If a `Foo` package is written appropriately, we could say `use Foo qw($bar); say $bar` where `$bar` is now a global variable in our package.
- With `our $foo`, we create a global variable in the current package if that variable doesn't already exist. The name of the variable is also made available in the current lexical scope, just like the variable of a `my` declaration.

The `local` operator does not create a variable. Instead, it saves the current value of a global variable and clears that variable. At the end of the current scope, the old value is restored. You can interpret each global variable name as a stack of values. With `local` you can add (and remove) values on the stack.
So while `local` can dynamically scope a value, it does not create a dynamically scoped variable name.

By carefully considering which code is compiled when, it becomes clear why your example doesn't currently work:

- In your main script, you load the module `funcs`. The `use` statement is executed in the BEGIN phase, i.e. during parsing.

  ```
  use warnings;
  use strict;

  package plshelp;
  use funcs;
  ```
- The `funcs` module is compiled:

  ```
  use warnings;
  use strict;

  package plshelp;

  sub change
  {
      ${$pointer} = 4;
  }
  ```

  At this point, no `$pointer` variable is in lexical scope and no imported global `$pointer` variable exists. Therefore you get an error. This compile-time observation is unrelated to the existence of a `$pointer` variable at runtime.

The canonical way to fix this error is to declare an `our $pointer` variable name in the scope of the `sub change`:

```
sub change {
    our $pointer;
    ${$pointer} = 4;
}
```

Note that the global variable will exist anyway, this just brings the name into scope for use as an unqualified variable name.

---

Just because you can use global variables doesn't mean that you should. There are two issues with them:

- On a design level, global variables do not declare a clear interface. By using a fully qualified name you can simply access a variable without any checks. They do not provide any encapsulation. This makes for fragile software and weird action-at-a-distance.
- On an implementation level, global variables are simply less efficient than lexical variables. I have never actually seen this matter, but think of the cycles!

Also, global variables are *global* variables: They can only have one value at a time! Scoping the value with `local` can help to avoid this in some cases, but there can still be conflicts in complex systems where two modules want to set the same global variable to different values and those modules call into each other.

The only good uses for global variables I have seen are to provide additional context to a callback that cannot take extra parameters, roughly similar to your approach. But where possible it is always better to pass the context as a parameter. Subroutine arguments are already effectively dynamically scoped:

```
sub change {
  my ($pointer) = @_;
  ${$pointer} = 4;
}

...
my $var = 3;
change(\$var);
```

If there is a lot of context it can be come cumbersome to pass all those references: `change(\$foo, \$bar, \$baz, \@something_else, \%even_more, ...)`. It could then make sense to bundle that context into an object, which can then be manipulated in a more controlled manner. Manipulating local or global variables is not always the best design.

Answer (score -1):

There's too much wrong with your code to just fix it

You've used `package plshelp` in both the main script and the module, even though the main entry point is in `main.pl` and your module is in `funcs.pm`. That's just irresponsible. Did you imagine that the `package` statement was solely for advertising for help and it didn't matter what you put in there?

Your post doesn't say what is wrong with what you have written, but it's surprising that it doesn't throw an error.

Here's something close that does what you seem to expect. I can't really explain things as your own code is so far from working

#### Functions.pm

```
package Functions;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT_OK = 'change';

sub change {

    my ($ref) = @_;

    $$ref = 4;
}
```

#### main.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Functions 'change';

my $var = 44;

print "$var\n";
change(\$var);
print "$var\n";
```

#### output

```
44
4
```

Comment: _Did you imagine that the package statement was solely for advertising for help and it didn't matter what you put in there:_ I imagined `package` was just for specifying the namespace of the subsequent code. If both `change` and the main script were to use variables in the same namespace, why not use the same namespace (`package`) in both places?

Comment: _I can't really explain things as your own code is so far from working:_ It's not that far from working actually. If I use `$plshelp::pointer` instead of `$pointer` in `funcs.pm`, the code works fine. It also works fine if I declare a global variable with `our $pointer` in `funcs.pm`. It also works fine if I remove the `use strict` directive.

Comment: I don't see anything that much _wrong_ with the code from a purely syntactic perspective. It is possible that this is a very bad way of achieving the thing I want to do, but the code is quite alright as far as the Perl compiler is concerned.

Comment: Coming to the code you have suggested, if I could pass an argument to the `change` function like you did using `change(\$var)`, why would I even go through so much trouble using dynamic scoping and all?